# RegEx - matching space in HTML string?

Tags: php, regex

To sanitise user input from a WYSIWYG editor, **I'm trying to find the following strings**:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p> </p>

<p></p>
```

**This is the regular expression I'm currently using**:

```
/\<p\>([nbsp\;]*|[\s]*|[ ]*)\<\/p\>/i
```

I'm quite new to RegEx, but from what I understand, this:

1. `\<p\>`: - Matches `<p>` exactly, then
2. `(` - Matches either:

   - `[nbsp\;]*` - "`nbsp;`" exactly, any number of times
   - `|[\s]*` - or any whitespace character, any number of times
   - `|[ ]*` - or " " (a space), any number of times
3. `<\/p\>` - Matches `</p>` exactly

However, **this expression only matches** `<p>nbsp;</p>` and not the other two.

I have also tried:

```
/\<p\>[nbsp\;|\s| ]*\<\/p\>/i
```

I am testing it using RegEx101.com ([first expression](https://regex101.com/r/zR9jY4/1), [second expression](https://regex101.com/r/tQ2wE5/1))

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use  "whole words" inside of a character class, the following will suffice ...

```
~<p>(?:&nbsp;|\s)*</p>~i
```

**Note:** You don't need to include `<space>`, the `\s` token will match the whitespace and you don't need to escape `<` and `>`, they are not considered special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `g` modifier for multiple matches.

```
/\<p\>([nbsp\;|\s| ]*[\s]*|)\<\/p\>/gi
```

https://regex101.com/r/zR9jY4/2

Answer (score 1):

You forget the amp; *&*

```
 /\<p\>[&nbsp\;|\s| ]*\<\/p\>/i
```

In example

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p> </p>

<p></p>
<p> asdfas</p>
```

This would match  the first 3

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use square brackets.

```
/\<p\>(&nbsp;*|\s*)\<\/p\>/i
```